# Hard-disk integrity after being dropped

Tags: hard-drive

My back up hard disks have all fallen from their shelf. I guess they were protected enough but how can I make sure of their integrity? I'd like to know if the data is still in there and if I can continue to use them.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use them and try reading the data.  If powered off, they will likely be fine as most modern hdds park their heads when they shut down.  The risk is that a drive platter was scratched by one of the heads, but parking helps prevent that.  Its possible some other physical damage occurred, but as i said reading random files is the only way to be sure.
you could also try a chkdsk.

Comment: I'd just change "you could also try a chkdsk"  to "run chkdsk!".  :-)